# Firebase with Android Studio Log in

Tags: android, firebase

I still don't know why I am getting this error. I already add all the dependencies and Files to my android studio project.

This is my root/build.gradle

```
    buildscript {    

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
}
```

this is my root/app/build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
 }
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And this is the Error: Notice that I have the google json right where it has to be

[image: Notice that I have the google json right where it has to be]

Answer (score 0):

I don't quiet understand what you are trying to do? Are you just trying to connect to Firebase and you are not able to? To use the authentication or what?

1- Have you tried tools -> Fire base and following those steps? It will automate everything for you. As I see in your screen shot just press "connect to firebase" and "Add Cloud Storage"

2- Do you already have a firebase account and project so you can connect to it?

Can you explain a bit more what do you mean by "Firebase with Android Studio Log in" ?!